# undo git pull of project

Tags: git, git-pull, pull

I do by error pull of a project on Github in local project so all project in local are deleted and replace by the github project.

**note:** the project on Github is Flutter project and the local project is Laravel one.

How can I find my Laravel project?

this some code maybe help to resolve this issue

```
$ git status .
On branch master
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    test.sh
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Pull doesn’t delete anything (that you can’t get back at least). May you give us more context?

Comment: `git pull` does the equivalent of running `fetch`, then `merge`. All your commits are still there (your most recent state most likely in `HEAD^`). If you do not have local changes, a hard reset will do. If you have local changes, stash before you reset.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

First you have to find out the *commit-hash* that was before the `git pull`.  (very easy with `git log`)

Then you can set back your local repo to the state from the previous commit. As example (the *commit-hash* must be adjusted with yours)

```
git reset --hard abc1234a
```

You can also look with `git reflog` and `reset` your local repository back with `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`